# Where can I find data on SDSS filter profiles?

Tags: telescope, photometry

I've seen lots of filter throughput curves for the SDSS, such as this one:

[image]

from the [SDSS camera page](https://www.sdss.org/instruments/camera/), but I'd really like to produce my own from the data. Is the filter response data per wavelength available somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Filter Profile Service](http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/) of the Spanish Virtual Observatory has the filter profiles for [Sloan](http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/index.php?mode=browse&gname=SLOAN&asttype=) along with many other filter systems, telescopes and spacecraft. The link above for Sloan will take you to an overview of the Sloan filter system and then there will be links for the "unprimed" and "primed" versions of the filter set. Clicking on the individual filters will give you a page of information like this:
[image: Screenshot of the Filter Profile Service showing the details for the Sloan i filter]
There are links to download the data in ASCII or VOTable format. Note that for the "unprimed" Sloan filters, along with some other systems, the effect of the atmosphere (hence that dip near 7600 angstroms) and instrument is included (see the `Transmission components` line), it's not the transmission of the just the filter itself.

Comment: Woah, more data than I could have hoped for! *drool*

Comment: It's a very useful service. Not sure whether you plan to access this programmatically but in Python+AstroPy you can directly read from the service e.g. `from astropy.table import Table ; sdss_i = Table.read("http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/fps.php?ID=SLOAN/SDSS.i")` (this uses the VOTable link from the above page to pull the Transmission vs Wavelength into a `Table`)